# Snakemake: wildcard restriction

Tags: python, python-3.x, wildcard, snakemake, expansion

I have the following `Snakemake` rules (I have only shown the relevant parts):

```
SAMPLE_IP = ['control_1_hif1a_hyp', 'control_2_hif1a_hyp']
SAMPLE_INPUT = ['control_1_input_hyp', 'control_2_input_hyp']

rule all:
    input:
        expand("bigwig/compare/{sample_ip}_vs_{sample_input}.bw", sample_ip=SAMPLE_IP, sample_input=SAMPLE_INPUT),]
    

rule bigwig_sample_vs_input:
    input:
        ip="mapped/{sample_ip}_dedup.bam",
        inpt="mapped/{sample_input}_dedup.bam",
    output:
        "bigwig/compare/{sample_ip}_vs_{sample_input}.bw",
    params:
        bs=config["general"]["bigwig"]["binSize"],
    threads: config["resources"]["deeptools"]["cpu"]
    resources: 
        runtime=config["resources"]["deeptools"]["time"]
    conda:
        "envs/chipseq.yaml"
    shell:
        "bamCompare -p {threads} -bs {params.bs} -b1 {input.ip} -b2 {input.inpt} "
```

The rule works but `Snakemake` creates four `.bw` files with these values:

```
sample_input: control_1_input_hyp
sample_ip: control_1_hif1a_hyp

sample_input: control_2_input_hyp
sample_ip: control_1_hif1a_hyp

sample_input: control_1_input_hyp
sample_ip: control_2_hif1a_hyp

sample_input: control_2_input_hyp
sample_ip: control_2_hif1a_hyp
```

But I only want to use:

```
sample_input: control_1_input_hyp
sample_ip: control_1_hif1a_hyp

sample_input: control_2_input_hyp
sample_ip: control_2_hif1a_hyp
```

How can I tell `Snakemake` to only combine the elements from `SAMPLE_IP` and `SAMPLE_INPUT` that have the same position in these lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `zip` option in `expand`, your directive for `input` in rule `all` would look like this:

```py
expand("bigwig/compare/{sample_ip}_vs_{sample_input}.bw", zip, sample_ip=SAMPLE_IP, sample_input=SAMPLE_INPUT),]
```